# Heel of Italy in Wikipedia?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, british-english, translation

Who can describe it for me? what does mean Heel and relation to italy?

the region situated on the "heel" of Italy.

Comment: Italy [looks like a boot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Italian_regions_provinces_white_no_labels.svg/455px-Italian_regions_provinces_white_no_labels.svg.png). The heel is, well, the heel. Btw, Italians themselves call their country "stivale" (boot).

Comment: yes @Mari-LouA I get it.

Comment: http://www.dagospia.com/img/foto/09-2010/69751.jpg

Comment: Related terms include the Thumb of Michigan, the Panhandle of Florida or Oklahoma, the Horn of Africa, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a [map](http://www.mapsofworld.com/italy/), Italy looks like a shoe. Presumably, the heel refers to the analogous portion.

Comment: analogous portion?

Comment: @JohnatanMorian The part of Italy corresponding to the heel of the shoe (on the map).

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the shape of the italian peninsula  is referred to as that of a boot (not shoe). The heel of that boot is the region known  as ***Puglia***

---

Note that ***boot*** is commonly used to refer to the morphology of Italy, for instance you can hear from e weather forecast phrases like: *heavy rain all over the boot.*

***[The heel of italy's boot](http://www.traveldudes.org/travel-tips/puglia-holiday-heel-boot-italy/26568)***:

[image]

[image]